# How can I split columns and values of whole dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
a\tb\tc     d\te\tf     g\th\ti

20\t21\t22  1\t2\t3     30\t31\t32
17\t18\t19  4\t5\t6     27\t28\t29
14\t15\t16  7\t8\t9     24\t25\t26
11\t12\t13  10\t11\t12  21\t22\t23
8\t9\t10    13\t14\t15  18\t19\t20
5\t6\t7     16\t17\t18  15\t16\t17
2\t3\t4     19\t20\t21  12\t13\t14
```

expected output:

```
    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i
0   20  21  22  1   2   3   30  31  32
1   17  18  19  4   5   6   27  28  29
2   14  15  16  7   8   9   24  25  26
3   11  12  13  10  11  12  21  22  23
4   8   9   10  13  14  15  18  19  20
5   5   6   7   16  17  18  15  16  17
6   2   3   4   19  20  21  12  13  14
```

My solution is:

```
l = list()
for column in df.columns:
    columns = column.split()
    d = df[column].str.split(expand=True)
    l.append(d.rename(columns=dict(zip(range(len(columns)),columns))))    
pd.concat(l,axis=1)
```

But this looks so complex.

Is there a simple way of doing this ?

Comment: I think thats a pretty elegant solution you got right there. One thing you could consider doing is: `columns=dict(enumerate(columns))` in the `rename` call.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach looks good. You can simplify the rename part by just assigning the new names to `.columns` attribute:

```
def expand(col):
    _df = df[col].str.split(expand=True)
    _df.columns = col.split()
    return _df

pd.concat(map(expand, df.columns), axis=1)

    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i
0  20  21  22   1   2   3  30  31  32
1  17  18  19   4   5   6  27  28  29
2  14  15  16   7   8   9  24  25  26
3  11  12  13  10  11  12  21  22  23
4   8   9  10  13  14  15  18  19  20
5   5   6   7  16  17  18  15  16  17
6   2   3   4  19  20  21  12  13  14
```